# In jade, how do i assign li item as selected based on object passed?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have main layout for header and it has navigation items. One of which will have class selected to represent the page the user is on. I want to assign selected class dynamically. How can i do so that i can render jade template and tell it which one to apply selected class on.

I can imagine doing it with javascript. But i'd like to know if jade has some way to do this without me writing whole logic from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [class attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/) for this. Let's say you had data like:

```
links = [
  {name: "home", uri: "/home", classes={selected: false}},
  {name: "about", uri: "/about", classes={selected: true}}
]
```

You could do this in jade

```
nav
  each link in links
    a(href=link.uri class=link.classes)
```